# Can Shotwell publish RAW CR2 photos?

Tags: canon, shotwell, google-plus

Can Shotwell be configured to publish the CR2 file to Google instead of the JPEG? I was extremely disappointed to discover that all the time I spend publishing photos was wasted because it used the JPEG versions!

Unfortunately the files it uploads are named IMG_xxx.CR2.jpg so that when you're viewing file details on Google, it hides the jpg extention and unless you notice the file is too small or download the full version you'll never know what happened.

It wouldn't be quite as bad if the JPEG was a 100% version, but it's not. If I use Lightroom the jpges are about 10 MB compared to Shotwell's 2 MB.

These are the RAW files supported: https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/15625?hl=en

Comment: Does Google Plus Photos / Picasa Web even support raw?  The page you linked to is for Picasa the desktop-based software, not Picasa Web / Google Plus Photos the online photo hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [official FAQ](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/other-raw.html):

> Shotwell can export your RAW photos in JPEG, PNG, TIFF or BMP format, and, when publishing, will internally export a JPEG version for you and publish that.

I'd guess that you can't make it publish as RAW. I tested it out on normal pics from a mobile camera (not RAW), and it did let me choose the size for publishing. Does it not offer that option for RAW images?